# How do I know which Displaylink Drivers / AMDGPU Drivers to use in Ubuntu 20.04 Kernel 5.10?

Tags: drivers, kernel, multiple-monitors

I started using Ubuntu on my machine and I can't get the settings for the graphics driver straight, my Displayport-Monitors are lagging heavily.

This is my setup:
https://store.hp.com/GermanyStore/Merch/Product.aspx?id=2W8S7EA&opt=ABD&sel=NTB
https://store.hp.com/GermanyStore/Merch/Product.aspx?id=5TW13AA&opt=ABB&sel=NCC

I run Ubuntu 20.04 on Kernel 5.10:
Output of lsb_release -a:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Output of Uname -r:

```
5.10.0-051000-generic
```

The graphics driver i use without success:

```
ii  amdgpu-core                                   20.20-1098277                               all          Core meta package for unified amdgpu driver.
ii  amdgpu-lib                                    20.20-1098277                               amd64        Meta package to install amdgpu userspace components.
ii  amdgpu-lib32                                  20.20-1098277                               amd64        Meta package to support i386 runtime on amd64 architecture
ii  amdgpu-pin                                    20.20-1098277                               all          Meta package to pin a specific amdgpu driver version.
ii  gst-omx-amdgpu                                1.0.0.1-1098277                             amd64        GStreamer OpenMAX plugins
ii  libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1:amd64                   1:2.4.100-1098277                           amd64        Userspace interface to amdgpu-specific kernel DRM services -- runtime
ii  libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1:i386                    1:2.4.100-1098277                           i386         Userspace interface to amdgpu-specific kernel DRM services -- runtime
ii  libdrm-amdgpu-common                          1.0.0-1098277                               all          List of AMD/ATI cards' device IDs, revision IDs and marketing names
ii  libdrm-amdgpu-radeon1:amd64                   1:2.4.100-1098277                           amd64        Userspace interface to radeon-specific kernel DRM services -- runtime
ii  libdrm-amdgpu-radeon1:i386                    1:2.4.100-1098277                           i386         Userspace interface to radeon-specific kernel DRM services -- runtime
ii  libdrm-amdgpu1:amd64                          2.4.102-1ubuntu1~20.04.1                    amd64        Userspace interface to amdgpu-specific kernel DRM services -- runtime
ii  libdrm-amdgpu1:i386                           2.4.102-1ubuntu1~20.04.1                    i386         Userspace interface to amdgpu-specific kernel DRM services -- runtime
ii  libdrm2-amdgpu:amd64                          1:2.4.100-1098277                           amd64        Userspace interface to kernel DRM services -- runtime
ii  libdrm2-amdgpu:i386                           1:2.4.100-1098277                           i386         Userspace interface to kernel DRM services -- runtime
ii  libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:amd64                     1:20.0.5-1098277                            amd64        free implementation of the EGL API -- runtime
ii  libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:i386                      1:20.0.5-1098277                            i386         free implementation of the EGL API -- runtime
ii  libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers:amd64             1:20.0.5-1098277                            amd64        free implementation of the EGL API -- hardware drivers
ii  libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers:i386              1:20.0.5-1098277                            i386         free implementation of the EGL API -- hardware drivers
ii  libgbm1-amdgpu:amd64                          1:20.0.5-1098277                            amd64        generic buffer management API -- runtime
ii  libgbm1-amdgpu:i386                           1:20.0.5-1098277                            i386         generic buffer management API -- runtime
ii  libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:amd64                  1:20.0.5-1098277                            amd64        free implementation of the OpenGL API -- DRI modules
ii  libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:i386                   1:20.0.5-1098277                            i386         free implementation of the OpenGL API -- DRI modules
ii  libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx:amd64                  1:20.0.5-1098277                            amd64        free implementation of the OpenGL API -- GLX runtime
ii  libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx:i386                   1:20.0.5-1098277                            i386         free implementation of the OpenGL API -- GLX runtime
ii  libglapi-amdgpu-mesa:amd64                    1:20.0.5-1098277                            amd64        free implementation of the GL API -- shared library
ii  libglapi-amdgpu-mesa:i386                     1:20.0.5-1098277                            i386         free implementation of the GL API -- shared library
ii  libgles1-amdgpu-mesa:amd64                    1:20.0.5-1098277                            amd64        free implementation of the OpenGL|ES 1.x API -- runtime
ii  libgles1-amdgpu-mesa:i386                     1:20.0.5-1098277                            i386         free implementation of the OpenGL|ES 1.x API -- runtime
ii  libgles2-amdgpu-mesa:amd64                    1:20.0.5-1098277                            amd64        free implementation of the OpenGL|ES 2.x API -- runtime
ii  libgles2-amdgpu-mesa:i386                     1:20.0.5-1098277                            i386         free implementation of the OpenGL|ES 2.x API -- runtime
ii  libllvm10.0-amdgpu:amd64                      1:10.0-1098277                              amd64        Modular compiler and toolchain technologies, runtime library
ii  libllvm10.0-amdgpu:i386                       1:10.0-1098277                              i386         Modular compiler and toolchain technologies, runtime library
ii  libosmesa6-amdgpu:amd64                       1:20.0.5-1098277                            amd64        Mesa Off-screen rendering extension
ii  libosmesa6-amdgpu:i386                        1:20.0.5-1098277                            i386         Mesa Off-screen rendering extension
ii  libxatracker2-amdgpu:amd64                    1:20.0.5-1098277                            amd64        X acceleration library -- runtime
ii  libxatracker2-amdgpu:i386                     1:20.0.5-1098277                            i386         X acceleration library -- runtime
ii  mesa-amdgpu-omx-drivers:amd64                 1:20.0.5-1098277                            amd64        Mesa OpenMAX video drivers
ii  mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers:amd64                  1:20.0.5-1098277                            amd64        Mesa VA-API video acceleration drivers
ii  mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers:i386                   1:20.0.5-1098277                            i386         Mesa VA-API video acceleration drivers
ii  mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers:amd64               1:20.0.5-1098277                            amd64        Mesa VDPAU video acceleration drivers
ii  mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers:i386                1:20.0.5-1098277                            i386         Mesa VDPAU video acceleration drivers
ii  xserver-xorg-amdgpu-video-amdgpu              1:19.1.0-1098277                            amd64        X.Org X server -- AMD/ATI Radeon display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu                     19.1.0-1                                    amd64        X.Org X server -- AMDGPU display driver
```

using

```
sudo ./amdgpu-install --no-dkms
```

on

```
amdgpu-pro-20.20-1098277-ubuntu-20.04
```

and the Displaylink driver:

```
displaylink-driver-5.4.0-55.153
```

I also tested the patch of using:

```
xserver-xorg-core_1.20.8-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

with no success.

It would be really great if someone here could help me figure out what is causing this massive lag on my other monitors.

Comment: Why are you on kernel 5.10? Have you tried using the device as it is configured during a clean install, or are/did you immediately move to replace the drivers?

Comment: @Nmath I tried using Kernel 5.8 as it was previously installed but I constantly ran into dependency issues with that, so I decided to upgrade 5.10 which was as I researched a stable version.